# Export Specific Registry Keys

Tags: powershell, registry, regedit

I have written a script to export specific registry keys and the sub keys inside it, but unfortunately my script get the keys, but not able to filter out the subkeys inside the item.

Please help me to get the subkeys for each object and export that data to CSV format.

```
$Servers = $env:COMPUTERNAME #Get-Content -Path 

Foreach ($vm in $Servers) {
$TCPIP_Interface = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces

foreach ($interface in $TCPIP_Interface){
Get-ItemProperty -Path $interface| Where-Object -Like DhcpIPAddress,DhcpNameServer,DhcpServer,DhcpDefaultGateway

}
#| Select-Object -Property DhcpIPAddress,DhcpNameServer,DhcpServer,DhcpDefaultGateway #| Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\TCPIP_Interface_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving the aspect of targeting multiple remote computers aside (for which you'd need [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) `-ComputerName $Servers { ... }`), you can simplify your code as follows (I'm also omitting the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) call):

```sh
$regPath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces'
Get-ItemProperty $regPath\* |
  Select-Object DhcpIPAddress,DhcpNameServer,DhcpServer,DhcpDefaultGateway |
    Where-Object { $_.psobject.Properties.Value -ne $null }
```

- Using wildcard path `$regPath\*` implicitly loops over all the child keys in `$regPath` and retrieves their properties.
- [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) `{ $_.psobject.Properties.Value -ne $null  }` filters out any of the custom objects created by the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call that do not at least have one non-`$null` property value, using the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject).

More work is needed in order to:

- Add a `Server` property that reflects the executing machine's host name.
- Convert the *array*-valued `DhcpDefaultGateway` property to a *string*-valued one, by joining potentially multiple addressed with `,` , so that exporting to a CSV works meaningfully (array-valued properties end up as verbatim `System.String[]` in a CSV).

Both can be achieved via [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
$regPath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces'
Get-ItemProperty $regPath\* |
    Select-Object @{
                     Name='Server';
                     Expression = { $env:COMPUTERNAME }
                  }, 
                  DhcpIPAddress, DhcpNameServer, DhcpServer, 
                  @{
                    Name = 'DhcpDefaultGateway';
                    Expression = { $_.DhcpDefaultGateway -join ', ' }
                  } |
      Where-Object { 
        $_.psobject.Properties.Where({ $_.Name -ne 'Server' }).Value -ne $null 
      }
```

Note: If you want to collect all information in a *single* CSV file on the *calling* computer, across all servers, do something like the following:

```sh
Invoke-Command -Servers $Servers { ... } | 
  Select-Object * -Exclude PS*, RunspaceId |
    Export-Csv C:\temp\TCPIP_Interface_Details.csv NoTypeInformation
```

- `-Exclude PS*, RunspaceId` excludes the properties that PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) automatically adds to all output objects.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call returned objects of type [`[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey).
- Passing them to [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) `-Path` *stringifies* them, resulting in a *registry-native* path to be reported; e.g.:

  ```sh
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{223a2c0a-88d9-11e6-b808-806e6f6e6963}
  ```
- PowerShell doesn't directly recognize such paths and assumes that they are (relative) *file-system* paths. To force their interpretation as a *registry* path, you have tree options:

  - Preferably, use the *pipeline* to supply the input path:

    ```sh
     # Note: This binds the .PSPath property value to the -LiteralPath parameter.
     $interface | Get-ItemProperty
    ```
  - Use the `.PSPath` property that PowerShell decorates the objects with:

    ```sh
     # Note: Parameter -Path implied; for full robustness, use -LiteralPath
     Get-ItemProperty $interface.PSPath
    ```
  - Prepend the `registry::` provider prefix to the registry-native path resulting from the stringification:

    ```sh
     Get-ItemProperty registry::$interface
    ```
- I presume that `Where-Object -Like DhcpIPAddress,DhcpNameServer,DhcpServer,DhcpDefaultGateway` is an attempt to filter out "empty" objects resulting from the `Select-Object` call, so that only objects that have actual values for the selected properties are returned and exported to CSV.

  - However, even *syntactically* this approach cannot work, because as of PowerShell 7.2.x you cannot implicitly apply an operation to each input object *as a whole* using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax); instead, you must specify a *property* to operate on, via the `-Property` parameter, to which the first *positional* argument implicitly binds.

    - That said, it *would* be convenient to be able to operate implicitly on each input object as a whole, and [GitHub issue #8357](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8357) proposes adding support for it.
  - Thus, your command is equivalent to the following, which fails, because `-Property` only supports a *single* property name (string):

    ```sh
    Where-Object -Property DhcpIPAddress,DhcpNameServer,DhcpServer,DhcpDefaultGateway -Like
    ```
  - Your logic therefore requires passing a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) to `Where-Object`'s (positionally implied) `-FilterScript` parameter, in which the input object as a whole can be referenced as usual, via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_). However, even your `-like` operation wouldn't work as intended; see the command at the top for how to filter out objects with only `$null` property values.

Answer (score 1):

Each `$interface` is an object with properties of which `.Path` is the interesting one.

Try:

```
$Servers = $env:COMPUTERNAME # Get-Content -Path 

$result = foreach ($vm in $Servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vm -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces' | ForEach-Object {
            Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath | Where-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Name -like 'Dhcp*' }
        }
    } | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.PSComputerName}}, 
                                DhcpIPAddress,
                                @{Name = 'DhcpNameServer'; Expression = {$_.DhcpNameServer -split ' ' -join '; '}},
                                DhcpServer, 
                                @{Name = 'DhcpDefaultGateway'; Expression = {$_.DhcpDefaultGateway -join '; '}}
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\TCPIP_Interface_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Of course, you may need to add parameter `-Credential` to the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet and supply a valid administrator credential</sup>