# Unable to add the Ping Response to Output variable

Tags: powershell, registry, ping, regedit

I have written a script to export specific registry keys and the sub keys inside it with the server ping response, but my scripts works as expected but the ping response value when I add it to output it is giving null

Please help me to get the ping response value for each server.

```
## Clear the host
Clear-Host

## Install Export-Excel Module if it is not installed
If (-Not (Get-InstalledModule -Name ImportExcel)){
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force 
}

## Set Script Location
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

## Out File Name
$FileName = "$PSScriptRoot\TCPIP_Interface_Details.xlsx"

## Get full list of servers
$Servers = GC -Path ".\Servers.txt"

## Delete if Old file exists
if (Test-Path $FileName) { Remove-Item $FileName
       write-host "$FileName has been deleted" -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta }
else { Write-host "$FileName doesn't exist" -BackgroundColor Red }

## Loop through each server
$Result = foreach ($vm in $Servers) {

## Check the Ping reponse for each server
Write-Host "Pinging Server" $vm
$Ping = Test-Connection -Server $vm -Quiet -Verbose 
    if ($Ping){Write-host "Server" $vm "is Online" -BackgroundColor Green}
    else{Write-host "Unable to ping Server" $vm -BackgroundColor Red}

## Check the Network Share path Accessibility
Write-Host "Checking Share Path on" $vm
$SharePath = Test-Path "\\$vm\E$" -Verbose
    if ($SharePath){Write-host "Server" $vm "Share Path is Accessible" -BackgroundColor Green}
    else{Write-host "Server" $vm "Share path access failed" -BackgroundColor Red}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vm {

## Get ChildItems under HKLM TCPIP Parameter Interface
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces' | ForEach-Object {
          Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath | Where-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Name -like 'Dhcp*' }
 } | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME+"."+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN}},
                             @{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = {if($using:Ping) {'Pinging'} else {'Unable to ping'}}}, 
                             @{Name = 'Share_Path_Access'; Expression = {if($using:SharePath) {'Accessible'} else {'Not Accessible'}}},
              DhcpIPAddress, @{Name = 'DhcpNameServer'; Expression = {$_.DhcpNameServer -split ' ' -join '; '}},
              DhcpServer,    @{Name = 'DhcpDefaultGateway'; Expression = {$_.DhcpDefaultGateway -join '; '}}
}}
$Result | Select-Object * -Exclude PS*, RunspaceId
```

Comment: I see you are using the code from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71677318/9898643) but didn't give me credit for it.. Oh well, add the ping result like `@{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = {$using:Ping}}`

Comment: This Works perfectly fine, instead of True or false can we get the output as "Pinging"  as True and "Unable to ping" as False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, just change your calculated property into

```
@{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = {$using:Ping}}
```

By scoping the variable `$Ping` with `using:`, it will be known in the scriptblock for Invoke-Command. Without that, the scritblock simply sees it as new, undefined variable (i.e. `$null`)

If as you commented, you would rather see some text instead of just `True` or `False`, have the expression in that calculated property output whatever you want like:

```
@{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = {if($using:Ping) {'Pinging'} else {'Unable to ping'}}}
```

---

Another way of letting the scriptblock know what `$Ping` is, is by adding this to the command as parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vm {
    param([bool]$Ping)
    # ... the rest of the scriptblock
    # now, you do not have to use the `using:` scope on $Ping
} -ArgumentList $Ping
```

---

---

To answer your latest comment, if pinging the machine did not work, there is really no reason to try and get properties from it using `Invoke-Command`. If you also want to have the non-pingables in your output, do:

```
$result = foreach ($vm in $Servers) {
    $Ping = Test-Connection -Server $vm -Quiet -Verbose 
    if ($Ping) {
        # we can reach this machine, so gather the properties we need and output an object
        # the 'Ping_Response 'can now be hardcoded
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vm -ScriptBlock {
            Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces' | ForEach-Object {
                Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath | Where-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Name -like 'Dhcp*' }
            }
        } | 
        Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.PSComputerName}}, 
                                @{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = { 'Pinging' }}, 
                                DhcpIPAddress,
                                @{Name = 'DhcpNameServer'; Expression = {$_.DhcpNameServer -split ' ' -join '; '}},
                                DhcpServer, 
                                @{Name = 'DhcpDefaultGateway'; Expression = {$_.DhcpDefaultGateway -join '; '}}
    }
    else {
        # return a similar object for machines that didn't respond to Ping
        # since we cannot reach this machine, most properties will be empty
        '' | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$vm}}, 
                                     @{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = { 'Unable to ping' }},
                                     DhcpIPAddress,DhcpNameServer,DhcpServer,DhcpDefaultGateway
    }
}
# output the results
$result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\TCPIP_Interface_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Just a small request, not related to the above question asked, but related to the same script.  In the above script I am exporting all the data to a excel file, how can I make a color for the Ping repsinse values, like for "Pinging" I need one color in excel output and for "Not Pinging" need another color, will that be possible

Comment: @nikonD3400 You could use the Excel COM object to manually add all details from `$Result` in a new workbook and set the interior colorindex property on those cells to any of the available colors, but perhaps it is much easier to use the much appreciated module [Import-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) for that. So, yes it is possible but I suggest you post a new question on how to do that or search for it here on SO (I know there are answers to be found)

Comment: For the original script, when i tried to expor the things to excel, the server which are not able to ping will not be appearing in the output file, only the servers which are accessible and pingable is getting printed in the output file.  Is there any way to get the output details of the servers which are not able to ping as well.

Comment: @nikonD3400 Please see my edit for that

Comment: I am checking share path access as well in my original script along with the Ping response, but when I tried the above solution which you provided for my Share access that is not working.  Original script is added in the question which have the Ping response code and the Share path access code, can you please help me to get the output details for Share path access as well.